# Compilation issue of a Scala worksheet in IntelliJ

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I have a worksheet containing

```
object test {

  val tableTest = new Array[String](1)
  tableTest.length

}
```

that returns

```
tableTest: Array[String] = [Ljava.lang.String;@628c5fdf
res0: Int = 1
```

and it seems ok.

However, when I enter this worksheet:

```
object test {

  val tableTest = new Array[String](1)
  tableTest(0) = "zero"

}
```

IntelliJ cannot compile and returns me a `Unable to read an event from: rO0ABXNyADdvcmcuamV0YnJhaW5zLmpwcy5pbmNyZW1lbnRhbC...` error.

Did I do something wrong?

Comment: I'm having a similar problem in IntelliJ build IC-135.475.

Comment: Same here, although my worksheet was working fine yesterday and nothing has changed. There is a ticket opened for this http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-6899.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having the same issue with latest Idea and Scala plugin.
It seems that the worksheet has a problem executing any line which evaluates to Unit. Assigning is Unit, that's why your `tableTest(0) = "zero"` fails.

I've temporarily solved it with the following workaround:

this line will fail with error `Error:Unable to read an event from:...`

```
println("Will fail")
```

You can fix it by defining this helper method and using it for any Unit expression:

```
def unit(f: => Unit): String = {f; ""}
unit(println("Will work"))
```

You just have to ignore the line it generates in the output panel with `res0: String =` 
You also can put this method in some object and import in any WS you need.

Gaston.
@ktonga