# How to get the option to create a new Scala Worksheet in IntelliJ?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I am using Kubuntu 14.4, I have Scala 2.9.2 installed and IntelliJ 2016.1 with the Scala plugin in version 3.0.2. When I create a new Scala project (not sbt project) and then right-click on `src` and then `new`, I expect the option to create a new Scala worksheet. However, I don't get that option. What do I need to do, to get the option?

PS: In fact I don't get any option related to creating Scala-something.

[image]

Comment: Have you defined the Scala SDK for the project?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: How do I do that and how do I check? Can't find the Settings in IntelliJ. I am new to IntelliJ.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: Thanks, I managed to get it done. If you post an answer how to define the Scala SDK for the project, I will except it.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Framework Support needs to be added to the project:

1. Right click on the project and choose `Add Framework Support...`
2. Click on `Scala` and set the settings.

Comment: Better set 2.10.4 as per this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23226478/scala-worksheet-not-working-in-intellij

Comment: Not getting scala under Add Framework Support.. but have already installed scala plugin

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

You can go to:

> File -> Project Structure -> Global Libraries (tab in left nav. bar)

Clear out any entries (if needed), then add the **scala sdk** back in. Ensure you click the **Download...** button. That's it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In version 2020.1 the worksheet option didn't show up because scala plugin was out of date and updating and restarting IDE started showing it.

File > Settings > Plugins > Downloaded > Scala

Hit update and restart IDE.

IDE hangs after restarting (at least for me). I had to kill and restart and like they say, third time was the charm.

Comment: still didn't show up in 2020.3 version even the plugin was updated

Answer (score 1):

The existing answers gave me the way.

I post here steps and screenshots specific to IntelliJ Idea Community Edition 2020.3 for Mac.

File menu > Project Structure

[image]

Platform Settings >  Global Libraries > + sign at the top of the window

[image]

Select the Ivy version

[image]

And you should get to this point, which is good:

[image]

Now you will get Scala Worksheet among the options of "New" from the contextual menu

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In multi-module maven project, the **Framework needs to be added to a specific module** as well, entire project doesn't cut it.
Also, mark the `src/main/scala` as Source.

Answer (score 0):

File -> Project Structure -> Global Libraries (tab in left nav. bar)
and download appropriate  scala  version