# Why can't i see scala worksheet option in intellij?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, intellij-scala

I have installed Scala in intellij and have created a project. But i cannot see scala worksheet option ?

Steps:
under scala project-->src-->main-->scala
right click on scala-->New -->I excect to see scala worksheet option

Thanks!!

Thanks!!

Comment: Try pressing *Ctrl-Shift-A* (Windows) *Cmd-Shit-A* (MacOs) and enter 'worksheet'. You should get options several actions including 'new scala worksheet' and create 'new light scala worksheet'.

Comment: It should be in the context menu, if you right click a folder, too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the option to create a new Scala Worksheet in IntelliJ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36867112/how-to-get-the-option-to-create-a-new-scala-worksheet-in-intellij)

Answer (score 1):

[How to get the option to create a new Scala Worksheet in IntelliJ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36867112/how-to-get-the-option-to-create-a-new-scala-worksheet-in-intellij)
This seems to do the trick. The asker has answered their own question, and it worked for me. There is probably a deeper issue (a setting that needs toggling), but worked for now. I know nothing deeper as I am setting up too.

Answer (score 1):

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> (Windows, Ubuntu) Cmd-Shift-A (MacOs)
2. Plugins
3. Installed
4. Scala
   4.1 If there is a problem with scala (e.g. IDEA doesn't support current version - update your IDEA/Scala)
   4.2 If there is no scala, go back to plugins and install it